# What is the difference between Xcode project and Xcode playground?

Tags: swift, xcode, swift-playground

I'm new to Xcode and swift and I'm trying to understand what's the difference between "starting with playground" and "creating a new xcode project"[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

An Xcode project allows you to create real apps that you could eventually upload to the App Store (providing you became an Apple Developer). An Xcode Playground allows you to play with code and test it out. It isn't for mainstream developing. Does that help?

Answer (score 1):

From Apples website:

> Interactive playgrounds help you to quickly prototype and build your applications, and simply provide another great way to interact with your code.

An Xcode *project*, however, creates a new asset folder and pre-made swift and storyboard files.

Answer (score 0):

A playground is only to test certain code, however, almost everything you do on a project you can do on a playground it will just be harder. A project also has a main.storyboard while the playground doesn't have one.